# Reading XLSM file with c# wihtout excel installed

Tags: c#

Hello so I was given a Project were I needed to read a `xlsm` file and then Project the result into a `DataGripView`, this is what I have so far.

```
var filename = "Filename|.xlsm"            
XLWorkbook workbook = null;
try
{
    workbook = new XLWorkbook(filename);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    labelResult.Text = "error message";
    return;
}

IXLWorksheet ws = null;
bool success = workbook.Worksheets.TryGetWorksheet("Cell", out ws);
if(!success)
{

    labelResult.Text = "error message.";
    return; 
}

List<MyList> listnum = new List<MyList>();
foreach (var row in ws.RowsUsed())
{

    MyList ML = new MyList {  };
    ML.statecod = row.Cell(1).GetString();
    ML.state = row.Cell(2).GetString();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = listnum;
}
```

So how do I populate my datagridview with the data from a xlsm file without having excel installed, therefore no excel libraries and no use of oledb?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hello, yes, sorry. So my question is, with what I have right now i cant display any result in my DGV , i made a pointbreak at "datagridview1.datasource = listnum" and it appears that is Reading the file but not showing in my form. How can i make the data be displayed into my dgv without excel or oledb?

Comment: For handling MS Office documents I'd check out [DocumentFormat.OpenXml on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

Comment: Checkout https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus, imo the best library for using Excel documents from C#. Lots of examples, no deed to have Excel installed (and anyhow much faster than the Interop libraries from MS)

Comment: Now it's giving me the error of a missing na element in the file. First gave me the error that na element was repeated so i changed the header. e.g: I had two headers called "data", so i changed one to "datas"(this in my excel file.). And now the error that the main part is missing when I press the button to load the file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. Just needed to add: listnum.add(ML);
I forgot to add my list, silly me...